# List main product subcategories of a product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hierarchical-data, taxonomy-terms

I have a category of WooCommerce products called "Product Types", and I'm trying to list all the categories underneath that, but NOT the child categories of those categories. For example, I have:

- Product Types

  - Carbide Milles
  - Fishing Tools

    - Child Category

I want it to list "Carbide Mills" and "Fishing Tools", but NOT "Child Category".

Here's the code I have:

```
<ul>
<?php $terms = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
            'child_of' => 32,
            'post__not_in' => 25,
            'depth' => 1,
            'include_children' => false,
    )
);

// Check if any term exists
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
    // Run a loop and print them all
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
            <li data-mh="234908ju243">
            <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </li>
        </a><?php
    }
} ?>
</ul>
```

But it's still returning the "Child Category". I'm not sure why limiting the depth to '1' and setting the 'include_children' to 'false' doesn't take care of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should need to use the argument `parent` with your "Product Types" term Id, to get the direct child terms *(subcategories)* as follow:

```
<ul>
<?php 
// Get the WP_Term object for "Product Types" product category (if needed)
$parent_term = get_term_by('name', 'Product Types', 'product_cat' )->term_id;

// Display "Product Types" category
echo' <a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $parent_term ) ) . '">' . $parent_term->name . '</a><br>';

// Get main direct subcategories
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent'     => $parent_term->term_id,
) );

// Check if any term exists
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
    // Loop through each term and print them all
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li data-mh="234908ju243">
        <a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>
        </li>';
    }
} ?>
</ul>
```

It should work.

I have changed a bit your html structure as the `<a>` tag need to be inside the `<li>` tag.